# how do you add constant value from a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have users with many roles and I want to mark those roles with numbers or priority numbers.

Ex:

Admin - 4

Client - 3

User - 2

Guest - 1

instead of adding a new column on my roles table which will look like this

| id | name | priority_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Admin | 4 |
| 2 | Client | 3 |
| 3 | User | 2 |
| 4 | Guest | 1 |

I was wondering if I could do it in my roles model class so I won't have to create a migration to my table and make it a constant value. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```rb
class User
  def priority_num
    case name
    when 'Admin'
      4
    when 'Client'
      3
    when 'User'
      2
    when 'Guest'
      1
    else
      raise StandardError.new "#{name} does not have a priority_num configured"
    end
  end
end
```

However, I'd probably add the column myself incase this expands more, and to keep it queryable without having to duplicate the rules in external reporting tools.

Comment: I think this will be the acceptable answer since I want it to return an integer. I don't think this will expand anytime soon because that is the only accepted user role we have. probably ill add on the comments. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use enum to make it easier to identify roles in your model without adding new migration.

```
enum priority_num: {guest: 1, user: 2, client: 3, admin: 4}
```

`User.first.priority_num` will return `"admin"`

You can compare to check if user is admin like this:

```
user.priority_num == "admin"
```

Comment: Thanks for responding sir. this would be nice if only it will return an integer because we have to check the current user priority number if it's lower than the profile being visited then you can view it, if it's higher or equal then you cannot visit it.

Answer (score 0):

@aRtoo

```
enum priority_num: {guest: 1, user: 2, client: 3, admin: 4}

user = User.first

user.read_attribute_before_type_cast(:priority_num)
```

gives you an integer of enum status